# Sorry the page you're looking could not be found. Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have laravel 5.5. Everything is working fine in it. I can access all routes.
But somehow I cannot access the route "/interest/{$id}".

This is my route.

```
<?php

Route::get('/interest/{$id}', [
    'uses' => 'IdeaController@createInterest'
])->name('interest.create')->middleware('auth');
```

I Can access every route accept this one. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you cannot use the dollar sign in your route var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dollar sign from your route parameter:

```
Route::get('/interest/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'IdeaController@createInterest'
])->name('interest.create')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('/interest/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'IdeaController@createInterest'
])->name('interest.create')->middleware('auth');

//in controller use method
public function createInterest($id){
}
```

Comment: Add a description of whats changed or why it dont work, code only answers are discouraged. Answers like this hit low-quality review.